# inspectdb -bash: /var/www/myproject/myproject/models.py: Permission denied

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, inspect, inspectdb

```
      sudo python2.7 var/www/myproject/manage.py inspectdb > /var/www/myproject/myproject/models.py

-bash: /var/www/myproject/myproject/models.py: Permission denied
```

On ec2 amazon web service can't inspectdb

Comment: Why would you be running that on EC2? That's something you do locally in development, to create your models files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the modles.py hasn't root permission. You can use `chmod 777 models.py` to change its permission.